# Android: Let Webview download text only (and work properly)

Tags: java, android

I want to use webview to render a login page. Thr webview is hidden in my app. Once the app is finished there will be some actions performed to login. (Since this is not a normal form, I really need to use WebView). But the big images on this site consume much bandwidth and the login takes longer. How can I disable the download of them and still get no errors in webview?

Comment: why not remove the parts with tags <img>

Comment: Removing img tags is not easy enough because I use loadUrl("www.example.com")

Answer (score 0):

You can stop loading the images in webview.

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Use this Github Library
it may be helped a lot.